# Is there IIS Microsoft Management Console in VS2005?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I am following a Microsoft guide on configuring an ActiveDirectory authentication from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx).

I am not able to locate IIS Microsoft Management Console in my Visual Studio 2005 for configuration, and I am only able to open ASP.NET Configuration tool.

I would like to ask if there is IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC) in Visual Studio 2005?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Information Services is not a part of Visual Studio 2005; rather it is part of the operating System.

If you are using the built-in Cassini server; then I'm afraid you won't be able to configure Windows Authentication. If you are using IIS, then you can open the MMC by going into "Run" in the Start Menu (or <kbd>Win Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and running `inetmgr`. If it says that this Program Cannot Be Found, then you do not have IIS installed.

Comment: thanks for the clarification of my doubts. I am stuck at this step of the tutorial: `Start the IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in.` Does it mean that 'Starting MMC from the command prompt outside of VS'?

Comment: @RUiHAO Yes. IIS Manager is a separate program from Visual Studio.